# Learning Div placement

Tags: css, html

Did a lot of research on all the separate components. However, I don't understand how the components work together. Several placement issues have plagued me on different occasions. I would like to understand why it behaves like it does.

Designing a site with a fixed header, containing some buttons. I want the buttons to be placed on a colored row (NAV). That's why I made  a child of NAV. However I can't seem to place the buttons over the bar.

Html

```
<body>
<nav class="row">
    <ul class="menu">
        <li id="link1"><a href="#link1">Link 1</a></li>
        <li id="link2"><a href="#link2">Link 2</a></li>
        <li id="link3"><a href="#link3">Link 3</a></li>
        <li id="link4"><a href="#link4">Link 4</a></li>
        <li id="link5"><a href="#link5">Link 5</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<div class="row main">
    @RenderBody()
</div>
```

CSS

```
nav, div, li {
        -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
        -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
        box-sizing: content-box;
        border: 1px dashed black;
    }

    .row {
        width: 100%;
        padding-left: 20px;
        padding-right: 20px;
    }

    nav {
        position: fixed;
        top: 80px;
        height: 40px;
        z-index: 100;
        background-color: Green;
        border-bottom: solid greenyellow 2px;
    }

    .menu li {
        display: block;
        background-color: darkgreen;
        float: left;
        height: 40px;
        width: 60px;
    }

    .menu a {
        color: white;
    }
```

Result
[image]

It can be fixed by several things, like button margin or placing the buttons relative with a negative Top offset. However, these solutions feel 'dirty', like it's not the right way to do it. Why are the LI's not on top of NAV?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

because your broswer applies by default some margin to the `ul` tag

try adding

```
ul {
    margin: 0;
}
```

you could avoid these issues by using a css reset (Eric Meyer is the authority here: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) or Necolas' Normalize.css: http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/

the first one zeroes all the values of all elements - you have to rebuild the style of some elements like lists.

The second one normalizes the values of elements to fix browsers inconsistencies

Answer (score 2):

When using the element ul it sometimes creates whitespace on browsers. By making the margin 0px you are removing the whitespace decreasing the area used by element. hope this helps. The following code can be used...

```
 ul {
 margin:0px
 }
```

Comment: This is a little brief to be considered an answer.  If you can elaborate on how this addresses the OP's issue, it'll keep it from getting deleted...

Comment: sorry. When using the element ul it sometimes creates whitespace on browsers. By making the margin 0px you are removing the whitespace decreasing the area used by element. hope this helps. thanks

Answer (score 2):

When you use the "float" property on some elements (here the "LI"), the parent (here the "menu") ignore his floating children to calculate his height.

So you have to specify a valid height to your menu, or probably better, use "overflow:auto" on it to remember him his children.

So remove your

```
nav {
    height:40px;
}
```

and add in your CSS :

```
.menu {
    overflow:auto;
}
```

As in this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/bE3QH/

Answer (score 2):

You can use this instead of your code.
You will get ready made menu control on this website.
You can modify as you  want & you will get your menu control available in a moment.
Here's the link.

http://cssmenumaker.com

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/07/16/slide-down-box-menu/

http://cssmenumaker.com/builder/1666948

Please check it out.
These are very useful and it will definitely save your time as well.

I hope this will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your CSS:

```
ul{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
```

This clears the default properties for ul elements

Answer (score 1):

You would be better off if you didn't specify a width and a height for the list items, but rather displaying the anchor tags as blocks, and giving *those* a width and height.